Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetNotPrecompiledError in MyEngine::Frontend#new
Asset hero_banner.jpg was not declared to be precompiled in production.
Declare links to your assets in app/assets/config/manifest.js.
//= link hero_banner.jpg
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << MyEngine::Engine.root.join('app', 'apps', 'themes', 'default_theme','assets','stylesheets')
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << MyEngine::Engine.root.join('app', 'apps', 'themes', 'default_theme','assets', 'images')

I have added this line in my assets.rb file in config in order to precompile some additional assets other than the conventional ones.
I have to add these line again in manifest files to see any changes on the view .
//= link default_theme.css
//= link new_theme.css
//= link hero_banner.jpg

The css files are present in the stylesheets folder, similarly the hero_banner is in the images folder of the precompiled assets. Instead of writing each file like this what should I do to compile all of them at once?

You can use your engine's manifest file:
// my_engine/app/assets/config/my_engine_manifest.js

//= link_directory ../../apps/themes/default_theme/assets/stylesheets
//= link_tree ../../apps/themes/default_theme/assets/images

Then add an initializer to precompile this manifest:
# my_engine/lib/my_engine/engine.rb

initializer "my_engine.themes" do |app|
  app.config.assets.precompile << "my_engine_manifest.js"
end

